# How can I get java's random generator to produce a double for variable in a constructor statement?

Tags: java, random, generator

Preface: I am new at this. 
Here is the source code file that won't compile because I get the error message that "method next double in class Random cannot be applied to given types."

```js
import java.util.Random;
public class Student
{
 private String name;
 private String address;
 private String major;
 private double GPA;
 
 Random generator = new Random();
 
 public Student (String studName, String studAddr, String studMaj)
 {
  name = studName;
  address = studAddr;
  major = studMaj;
  GPA = generator.nextDouble(.5, 4.0);
 }
 
 public Student (String studName, String studAddr)
 {
  name = studName;
  address = studAddr;
  major = "undeclared";
  GPA = generator.nextDouble(.5, 4.0);
 }

​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Paul John said, Random.nextDouble() doesn't take any arguments. For what you're trying to do, you'd want code that would look like this:

```
GPA = 3.5*generator.nextDouble()+0.5;
```

That will give you a random double with a value between 0.5 and 4.0, because nextDouble() returns a random value between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for this--it's exactly the parameter information that I was missing. The API and StackOverflow have been my saviors this semester! I've only asked this one question but have gotten hundreds of answers from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The method java.util.Random.nextDouble() does not take arugments
SO change it to

```
   GPA = generator.nextDouble()
```

LInk to documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html